# Python package handling PDF/A-3 compliance?

Tags: python, pdf, pdfa3

I try to use python to generate a PDF with PDF/A-3 Compliance. My question are as follows:

1. Are there any packages that generate a PDF with PDF/A-3 Compliance?
2. Are there any packages that able to convert any PDF to PDF/A-3?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

[Spire.PDF for Python](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/pdf-for-python.html) module can be used to convert PDF to PDF/A-3a or PDF/A-3b.

Here is a simple example:

```
from spire.pdf.common import *
from spire.pdf import *

# Specify the input file path and output folder
inputFile = "Sample.pdf"
outputFolder = "Output/"

# Create an object of the PdfStandardsConverter class
converter = PdfStandardsConverter(inputFile)

# Convert the input file to Pdf/A-3a
converter.ToPdfA3A(outputFolder + "ToPdfA3A.pdf")

# Convert the input file to Pdf/A-3b
converter.ToPdfA3B(outputFolder + "ToPdfA3B.pdf")
```

Here is the resultant file:
[image]

Note I work for the company that developed this module.